# Pine Scripts: Bars-length of last & latest golden cross as well as latest death cross

Tags: pine-script

I am new to pine scripts. I wanna calculate the Bars length of last Golden Cross (Crossover 10 sma x 20 sma) and the bars length of last Death Cross (Cross under 10 sma x 20 sma) and latest Golden Cross again.

Example: Telsa (SMA 10 x SMA 20)
Last Golden Cross: 7 Oct 2020
15 Bars till Death Cross
Latest Death Cross: 28 Oct 2020
12 Bars till Golden Cross
Latest Golden Cross: 13 Nov 2020
26 Bars till now (23 Dec 2020)

How can I make a label to show GC 15, DC 12 and GC 26 in box?
I can't even locate the latest, last location of GC and DC.

Much appreciated for your help.
Regards,

```
//@version=4
study("MA")

sma20=sma(close,20)
sma50=sma(close,50)


GC = (sma20 >= sma50) 
DC = (sma20 <= sma50) 

plot(series=barssince(GC), title="GC", color=color.blue, linewidth=2)
plot(series=barssince(DC), title="DC", color=color.red, linewidth=2)

Diff=barssince(GC)-barssince(DC)
//plot(Diff, title="DC", color=color.green, linewidth=2)
hline=0
plot(hline)

net=highest(Diff,100)+lowest(Diff,100)
//plot(-net,color=color.purple, linewidth=3)

/// Make a new label once
var label myLabel = label.new(x=bar_index, y=net,
     textcolor=color.white, color=color.blue)

// On the last bar, show the chart's bar count
if (barstate.islast)
    // Set the label content
    label.set_text(id=myLabel, text="GDG\n" +
         tostring(net))

    // Update the label's location
    label.set_x(id=myLabel, x=bar_index)
    label.set_y(id=myLabel, y=net)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your (net) supposed to do so i just leave it there, but as for the counter, this should do the trick:

```
//@version=4
study("MA")

sma20=sma(close,20)
sma50=sma(close,50)

GC1 = (sma20 >= sma50) 
DC1 = (sma20 <= sma50) 
GC = crossover(sma20, sma50) 
DC = crossunder(sma20, sma50) 

var counter   = 0
var lastgc    = 0
var lastdc    = 0
var currstate = ""

counter := counter+1

if(DC)
    currstate := "DC"
    lastgc    := counter
    counter   :=0
if(GC)
    currstate := "GC"
    lastdc    := counter
    counter   :=0

lbltxt = "Current State: "+currstate+" BarSince: "+ tostring(counter)
  + "\nPrevious GC BarCount : "+tostring(lastgc)
  + "\nPrevious DC BarCount : "+tostring(lastdc)

// plot(series=barssince(GC1), title="GC", color=color.blue, linewidth=2)
// plot(series=barssince(DC1), title="DC", color=color.red, linewidth=2)

Diff=barssince(GC1)-barssince(DC1)
//plot(Diff, title="DC", color=color.green, linewidth=2)
// hline=0
// plot(hline)

net=highest(Diff,100)+lowest(Diff,100)
//plot(-net,color=color.purple, linewidth=3)

/// Make a new label once
var label myLabel = label.new(x=bar_index, y=net,
     textcolor=color.white, color=color.blue)

// On the last bar, show the chart's bar count
if (barstate.islast)
    // Set the label content
    label.set_text(id=myLabel, text=lbltxt+"\nGDG\n" +
         tostring(net))

    // Update the label's location
    label.set_x(id=myLabel, x=bar_index)
    label.set_y(id=myLabel, y=net)
```

Comment: You are awesome. Thank you so much. Could you do me a favor that can add a sign which meet the condition of previous GC length is longer than previous DC length. I couldn't do it by myself....  plotchar((lastgc-lastdc)>=0, char='O', color=#363A45, location=location.belowbar). Thanks always